# Facebook SSO for Android can I ask for login and permission all in one time

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Basically I'm setting a button on my android game for when a user gets a highscore he can share it on facebook in his timeline

I've used the facebook sdk for this, based on the hellofacebook example, but instead of and update status is a post to the timeline, the permission is the same, "publish_actions" my problem is, the first time the user uses the share button, I show the facebook LoginButton, when clicked it redirects to the fb page where the user must accept the app to use hes account, and then back to my activity, now with the share button activated, but when I click Share, it goes again to that same page to ask the autorization of the user to publish, only after that my app can finnally publish on the users timeline

Now I understand why this happens, cause the first time I made a request to get a session for read, without the permission "publish_actions" and the second time I ask for the permissions, I tried to set the permissions at the first request, I get an error, cause I cant ask for publish permissions in a read session. And I cant ask for a opentoPublish before I get the first session for read.

Is there an easy way to get the session already with the publish permission just in 1 go ??

Or better yet, without asking for the user permission, logging by itself via sso, with the publish permission, so that the user only sees the share button, and it just shares my info in hes timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new SDK, you are required to ask for write permissions (such as "publish_actions") separately from read permissions.  There is no way to ask for both types of permissions at the same time.

The suggested best practice is to auth the user with your read permissions when they first use your app, and when the user gets a high score, provide a share button which will auth the user once again but this time with write permissions.  This only needs to be done once so when they want to share their high score again they don't need to go through the auth dialog.

Comment: ok, I get it, so the way I'm using it is the correct way, but maybe I can just set a button on the main menu just for authentication and then just use the share button to publish, thanks Jesse

Comment: Correct, if this answer has helped you please make sure to accept it.

Comment: I tried this solution, and when I press the share button reorders authentication, this is normal behavior?