# Integrating Facebook into android - login permissions

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions

I am in the process of integrating Facebook login into the android app I am developing.

I would like the app to be authorised to post/publish to feed/timeline.  At present the user is receiving two login permissions screens (One for the initial login and a second one is appearing for the post permission).  This isn't an ideal user experience.

How do I incorporate the permission to post into the permission screen that appears when the app asks the user to login to Facebook.

Having done some research it appears other apps can gain the authentication at the point of login and not require a re-login permission screen to appear with the post permission included.

I'm clearly missing something.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possible copy of: [Facebook SSO for Android can I ask for login and permission all in one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312163/facebook-sso-for-android-can-i-ask-for-login-and-permission-all-in-one-time)

Bottom line is: "With the new SDK, you are required to ask for write permissions (such as "publish_actions") separately from read permissions".

Answer (score 0):

As you said it isn't an ideal user experience, I used a similar way to implement the login a user using sdk facebook, I follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) tutorial and it should show to the user only one login, and then a screen showing the post permission, without having to make log in again.

this